# Bibtex webpage citations, including journal and title?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, urls

I'm working on a LaTeX bibliography using `natbib` and `apa-good.bst` that includes a number of web sources, including both websites and newspaper articles published online.

Based on other responses on StackExchange, I'm formatting my sources as:

```
@misc{buckley_new_2012,
 title = {In New York's public housing, fear creeps in with the dark},
 howpublished = {\url{http://www.nytimes.com/2012/11/03/nyregion/in-public-housing-after-hurricane-sandy-fear-misery-and-heroism.html?pagewanted=all}},
 note = {Accessed: 2012-11-19},
 journal = {The New York Times},
 author = {Buckley, C. and Wilson, M.},
 month = nov,
 year = {2012}
}
```

However, it seems that having a value for howpublished represses display of the journal title.  How do I get both the URL and the journal title to show up in my bibliography?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can try `@article` instead of `@misc` and remove `howpuplished`, and use `url = {http://www.nytimes.com/2012/11/03/nyregion/in-public-housing-after-hurricane-sandy-fear-misery-and-heroism.html?pagewanted=all},` instead

Comment: Doesn't the `month` need to be in braces too? `{November}`...? or try removing it all together and recompiling.

Comment: @Reanimation - many bibtex bibliography style files "know" about the strings `jan`, `feb`, etc being shortcuts for "January", "February", etc.

Comment: @Mico Oh really? I only posted it because I had the same problem with a `@misc` entry recently.

Comment: @Reanimation - Which bibliography style do you use? The bibliography style file `apa-good.bst`, which is what the OP uses, has the instruction `MACRO {nov} {"Nov."}`. Thus, no error or warning message will be issued when `month = nov` is encountered.

Comment: I hadn't spotted the style file used until you just mentioned it. I use a class template that uses `apalike` which explains why I experienced that issue.

Comment: Changing the format to `@article` and using `url = {http://www.nytimes.com/2012/11/03/nyregion/in-public-housing-after-hurricane-sa‌​ndy-fear-misery-and-heroism.html?pagewanted=all}` does cause the url to appear (along with the text "URL"), but the url now spills over into the margins.  Is there a better way to do this?